# "This pdf document cannot be displayed" when downloading files with Php?

Tags: php

[image]

```
  if(isset($_POST["down"])){
$id = $_POST['id'];

  $ebook2=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM ebook where ebook_id=:id");
  $ebook2->execute(array(
  'id'=>$id
  ));
  $ebookcek2=$ebook2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


  $pdf = $ebookcek2['ebook_file'];
  $slug = permalink($ebookcek2['ebook_ad']);

$file_url = "assets$pdf";

if (!file_exists($file_url)) {

}else{
  header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
  header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$slug.pdf");
  header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
  readfile($file_url);
}
}
```

I am downloading the pdf file with php but when I try to open it I get the error "This pdf document cannot be displayed". What do you think could be the problem?

Comment: your pdf file is probably corrupted

Comment: Call the function via curl and look what you get back. I guess it is not a valid pdf

Comment: Seems like the PDF is stored on disk on your server. Go and open that file directly (without going via the PHP script). Does the file open correctly then?

Comment: However, when I open the pdf file in my folders myself, it opens without error. Could there be something missing in the header codes?

Yes, the file open correctly

Comment: It's not obvious. However, your script says `if(isset($_POST["down"])){ .. }`...so what happens before and after this `if` block? Is there some other code elsewhere in the same PHP file? If so, and if that code contains anything which could be output (e.g. echo or print statements, raw HTML, even just blank spaces) then that output will also be put into the downloaded PDF, which would probably corrupt it. Check your script file for that, and also open the original PDF and the downloaded PDF in a text editor such as Notepad++ and see if there's any extra content in the downloaded one.

Comment: That's right, the codes below the downloaded file are corrupting the pdf. Problem solved, thank you "ADyson".

Comment: _Side note suggestion:_ Instead of having: `if (!x) {} else {....}` (like your `if (!file_exists($file_url))`), you can make it cleaner by just doing: `if (x) { ... }` (inverted statement) and omit the `else` completely.

Answer (score 2):

You have something else in your PHP script which is outputting content, and this is being included in the downloaded PDF file, and therefore corrupting it.

You should either make sure there is no other output before or after the `readFile` command, and/or use `exit();` directly after the `readFile` command so that the script stops and does not output anything else. (That assumes there is no output *before* `readFile`, of course).